# AddThis. LinkedIn sharing is not working on iPhone

Tags: linkedin-api, addthis

When I try to share my page with AddThis to Linkedin it is working fine from desktop, but even the same URL is not working when I do just the same from iPhone.

To test it:

1. Open AddThis home page and click share to LinkedIn button. As a result I have http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.addthis.com%2F%23.Tt3z80Hs1Wo.linkedin&title=AddThis+-+Share+Button%2C+Social+Bookmark%2C+Sharing+Plugins+and+Module&ro=false&summary=&source= opened in my browser, which is working fine.
2. Try to open just the same URL from an iPhone. I have the following error in this case: "*We’re sorry. Something unexpected happened and your request could not be completed. Please close this window and try again.*"

Sounds like LinkedIn API issue. Any ideas how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem this morning. After some digging it turns out that the linkedin http sharearticle API has been deprecated:

https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/9492#comment-9492

, alternatives are the JavaScript API and the REST API which I can't link to as I don't have enough reputation. However they are easy to find on the Linkedin developer pages. Simple JavaScript for a Linkedin share button can be automatically constructed for you here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-button

. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if AddThis plan to change their ways to share to LinkedIn and use the new API?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to update your URL format to conform to the [**Official Microsoft "Share on LinkedIn" Documentation**](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=%7Burl%7D).  The format of your URL should be...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Furthermore, parameters like `source`, `title`, and `summary` have all been deprecated, but you can replicate their behavior again by setting the appropriate `og:` tags in the HTML of your web page, which is good standard anyway.  Quoting from **[Official LinkedIn "Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn" Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**, just put these into your page's HTML:

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

If you make these adjustments, sharing on your page *should* behave just like it once did!